# Creating Image Gallery using Drawable with prefix and without xml

Tags: android

In my drawable folder, i have : 
decouvrir_0_0.jpg,
decouvrir_0_1.jpg,
decouvrir_0_2.jpg,
decouvrir_1_0.jpg,
decouvrir_1_1.jpg,
....

i would make a dynamic gallery with the drawables who begin with a prefix (ex : decouvrir_0, decouvrir_1, ...) gave by the intent i :
getResources().getIdentifier(i.getStringExtra("IdDecouvrir").toString()

=>1 prefix = 1 gallery

=>I put new jpgs in drawable = new gallery

I found the example in the API with Integer[] mImageIds ={ R.drawable.decouvrir_0_0,........ but I don't want use a array.xml

an idea or it's impossible ?

I tried a lot of answers of this forum, and nothing works...

Comment: PPS : hi wonko79, why did you remove 'thanks a lot' at the end of my post ^^ (and 'hello' and 'sorry for my english' at the beginning...)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean Res_exists = true;
int k=1;
do{
String Resou = getIntent().getExtras().getString("categorie").toString()+"_" + k;
int test = getResources().getIdentifier(Resou, "drawable", getPackageName()); 

        if (test != 0) 
        {   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),mImageIds[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // displays an Int, array OK
            //mImageIds[1] = test; //try 1
            //mImageIds[k] = getResources().getIdentifier(Resou, "drawable", getPackageName()); // try 2 problem is here
            //mThumbIds[k] = getResources().getIdentifier(Resou+"_t", "drawable", getPackageName()); // try 3
            k++;
            //break;
        }
        else
            {Res_exists = false; break;}
    }
    while (Res_exists = true);



private Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.decouvrir_0_0_t};
private Integer[] mImageIds = {R.drawable.decouvrir_0_0};
```